# How to call a Controller from button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="details" value="@scr.Id">Details</button>
```

and I want to redirect it to my controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int par)
{
    var screening = _context.Screenings.Single(s => s.Id == par);
    return View(screening);
}
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: change your tag to MVC.. this is not asp.net

Comment: You don't need "jquery" - just a basic anchor/href which you can use an `@Html` helper to generate in a number of ways.

Answer (score 1):

change you button to something like this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Your Controller Name", new {@class = "btn btn-info"})
```

and it should work fine no need for JQuery

if you need jQuery

use ajax call

```
$("#details").click(function() {
 $.ajax({url: "/ControllerName/Details/YourIDValue", success: function(result){

    }});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `JQuery` to send id of the button you can try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#details").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "ControllerName")?par=' + $(this).val();

            }
        );
    });
```